# Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'claimSystemId' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-aurora

We are using `mysql` package in `Node.Js` for connection to Aurora DB.

We are calling a Stored Procedure and sometimes we get `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'claimSystemId' in 'field list'` error.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`CLIroham`@`%` PROCEDURE `spGetMasterData`(IN documentIdParam bigint)
BEGIN
select stateId AS id,stateName AS  name  from  state;
select countryId AS id, countryName  AS  name  from  country;
select statusCode AS id, status AS name from  statusMaster where type_of_status = 'Client_Instruction_Status';
select statusCode AS id, status AS name from  statusMaster where type_of_status = 'PROGRAM_STATUS';
select personId AS id, firstname AS name  from person where employeeType = 'AE' limit 20;
select naicsCodeId AS id, naicsCode as name   from  naicsMaster limit 20;
select clientId AS id , name AS name from client limit 10;
select doc.revNumber as revNumber ,concat(p.firstname,' ',p.lastname) as createdBy,
doc.lastModifiedDate as lastModifiedDate, doc.revChangesText 
from documentHistory as doc JOIN person as p on p.personId=doc.lastModifiedBy
where doc.documentId = documentIdParam
order by revNumber desc;
select claimSystemId As id, Name as name  from  claimSystem;
END
```

We checked our DB and "claimSystemId" column exists. We tried positioning different select statement in the stored procedure but each time error is not frequent and remains the same.

The mysql connection details are as follows:

```
exports.pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "###",
    user: "##",
    password: "##",
    port: "3306",
    database: "##",
    multipleStatements: true
});

DB.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (!!err) {
        //console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        connection.query("call spGetMasterData(?)", _documentId, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {

                connection.release();
                var errorResponse = {
                    "errorMessage" : "Retry"
                }
                res.send(errorResponse)
                return
            }
            else {
                //.....
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you got select claimSystemId in table claimSystem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% here but I believe that when you are passing the value you need to make sure that you are truncating the value with `${value}` and if the value if the value you are trying to pass is a string then you will need `'${string_value}'` which it looks like '_documentId might be, but it looks like the error is on line with your connection.query();